# Recommended Backup Tool for Elementary OS

Tags: system-installation, filesystem, backup

Is there a backup tool that the Elementary team recommends, even though they do not directly support the software? Or is there a technique within the OS I have yet to discover?  There is talk of Timeshare in the responses I have seen but I cannot find it in the App Centre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My tool of choice is Back in Time. It's very versatile (incremental backups, local/cloud, enrypted/non encrypted etc.) and has a clear GUI that allows you to keep track of your backups and restore (complete folders or single files, as you like) very easily. It should be in the repositories if I remember correctly. If not, check here: https://github.com/bit-team/backintime

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what the elementary developers would recommend, but I can make a personal recommendation for a nice GTK3 back up app called [Backups](https://appcenter.elementary.io/deja-dup.desktop). It's in the AppCenter and can be easily installed and configured. I use it to back up my /home directory to an external drive, that then gets pushed once a week to Google Drive via a cron job.

There are other backup options out there, but personally I've found Backups to work well for my needs.

Best of luck to you!